# “We can’t tell if your pc has enough space to install Windows 11” Windows 11 ISO

Tags: windows-10, windows-11

I get this error, my board has TPM and safe boot but my CPU is unsupported (i5-6400). I have bypassed that but I still get this error (installing through USB will prolly work but I want to keep my data). I have a 256GB Samsung SSD so enough space… any way to fix this? (Latest windows 10 version)

Tried posting this on reddit but windows subreddits always have infinite rules...

Comment: How much space is available on your drive right now?

Comment: Also you have to use Windows 11 Insider.  Your system does not support Production.

Comment: @John around 80GB

Comment: Windows 11 will install in 80GB. Use the insider versions

Comment: @John - The same compatible rules are applied to Insider Preview builds, I would say that they might even be more strict, since the rules are updated as the requirements change.

Comment: Alright, will try it, thanks!

Comment: The problem might be the size of your EFI partition. How big is it?

Comment: @harrymc hmmm, not sure, will check

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GcjAaSrNje8